# Partial derivative of metric

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Lets say I have a sequence of Riemannian metrics $(h_{\lambda})$. Is there any way to express the partial derivative

$$\frac{\partial h^{ij}}{\partial\lambda}$$

in terms of

$$\frac{\partial h_{ij}}{\partial\lambda}?$$

I cannot simply raise indices, since the partial derivative is in general not a tensor. What I have tried is using the face that $h^{ij}h_{ij}=d$, where $d$ is the dimensional of our manifold, which yields

$$h^{ij}\frac{\partial h_{ij}}{\partial\lambda}=h_{ij}\frac{\partial h^{ij}}{\partial\lambda}$$

but I don't know how to continue from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't sum over all indices. Instead, write
$$h^{ij}h_{jk}=\delta_{k}^j$$ so
$$\frac{\partial (h^{ij}h_{jk})}{\partial \lambda}= 0 =  \frac{\partial h^{ij}}{\partial \lambda}h_{jk}+ h^{ij}\frac{\partial h_{jk}}{\partial \lambda}$$
Now you can solve for $\frac{\partial h^{ij}}{\partial \lambda} $ by contraction with $h^{kl}$.

Comment: Equivalently, if $M(t)$ is a family of invertible matrices, then $(M^{-1})'(t) = -M^{-1}(t)M'(t)M^{-1}(t)$.